# wordpress Request 404/410 responses missing fonts

Tags: wordpress, fonts, http-status-code-404

I try to fix the website speed for that I visit gtmetrix to check the exact speed and errors from last seven days one error continuously display there its called web fonts, even I try a lot but still didn't find the proper way to resolve this issue.

I tried turning off plugin one-by-one, but that didn't make any difference, so I know it's not a plugin conflict. I'm looking at the font files on the server, so I know they are there. Any ideas what to try next?

Currently, i am using Fetch Wordpress Theme its free, for reference, I provide the web page test result [link](https://gtmetrix.com/reports/www.mymastichat.com/NekCj9Zy) please advise.

Comment: your theme is requesting a font that does not exist on your server. `...fetch/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.3.0`. In your theme find where you are including the font and remove it.

Comment: I Fix this bug the problem in the wp-hide because of this errors coming once i disable its work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Issue Happen Because of the Usage Of Plugin Wp-Hide, Once You Use The Plugin Very Carefully Because If You Mis Configure The Page Speed & Web Page Score Effected.